# Vertice Manipulation Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm basically new the Three.js, and I'm trying to make a simple `PlaneGeometry`.

The program flow would be like this:

- The user will input his/her desired height and width for the `PlaneGeometry`
- The browser will display the plane with the user's desired height and width

The problem though is that I cannot find ways to make this possible, I've read some articles about this but they are not giving me the right answers for my problem. Can someone at least point me where it will be usefull ? Ort alter my code?

```
<form method="POST" action = "">
    <input type=button value="Resize" onclick="resizeverti" />
    <input type=text id="width" />
    <input type=text id="height" />
 </form>

<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function resizeverti()
    {
    var widthsize=parseInt(document.getElementById('width').value);
    var heightsize=parseInt(document.getElementById('height').value);    

    theVerti.geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( widthsize, heightsize, 0 ) );
    theVerti.geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( widthsize, heightsize, 0 ) );
    theVerti.geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( widthsize, heightsize, 0 ) );
    theVertigeometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
    };
  resizeverti();
  var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a "PlaneGeometry" in place. See Three.Planegeometry(). Using this function you can create planes of various sizes with user-defined subdivisions etc. Just use this one!

If the user changes the size of the plane, just remove it from scene and create a new one with the current user-defined parameters